# Menubar like ES Explorer in android

Tags: android, xml, file, user-interface

I want to achieve this:

[image]

What I tried to do is to add a button and spinner side by side and the UI looks horrible.How can I achieve an UI like this (red marked)? Thanks in advance.

What I have tried so far:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/storageDirectory"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
        android:textSize="12dip"
        android:layout_weight=".5"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/frame"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:textSize="12dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"/>
</LinearLayout>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/fileList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's recommended to replace the `ActionBar` with a `ToolBar`. Have a look here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html - what you're asking for is just a `Spinner` a `TextView` and an `ImageView`.

It could look something like this:

[image]

The XML layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
        android:paddingTop="0dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:weightSum="1.1">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="/"
                android:textSize="22sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.1"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The `MainActivity` class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, new String[]{"Test 1", "Test 2", "Test 3", "Test 4", "Test 5", "Test 6", "Test 7", "Test 8", "Test 9", "Test 10"}));
    }
}
```

Hope this helps. The key idea is to use a `ToolBar` that you can customise completely the way you want it basically :-)